# Open Cart Product per row

Tags: php, css, opencart

I am using open cart for my shoping cart. I want to show three products per row in the featured module.

I have searched for it and found  [This](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=16794). But i cant find the `$i = $i + .......` in my .tpl files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forum post that you found is out of date. That is a 1.4.X version, and I'm guessing you're on the 1.5.X version now instead. Really you should be using css to do this as it's coded originally to fit the width